# How to expand equation to textwidth?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, width

I have an equation like so:

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:helper_params}
    \tilde{B} = \begin{bmatrix} CB\\B \end{bmatrix}, \tilde{I} = \begin{bmatrix} I_p\\0 \end{bmatrix},
    \tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_e & 0\\0 & Q_x \end{bmatrix}, \tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{I}\quad \tilde{F} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

which produces this:

---

[image]

---

I would like to automatically expand the space between each matrix such that the whole equation fills the textwidth (or linewidth or any other predefined similar constant). I want to achieve something similar to this:

---

[image]

---

Are there any mechanisms for this goal?

Comment: Instead of creating huge white gaps between the "blocks" of the equation, you may be better off inserting a standard spacer such as `\quad` after each of the three commas.

Comment: @Mico I fully agree (see my answer).

Comment: @Mico, you are right. But the point is using `quad` not necessarily satisfies what I want. Imagine if there were three matrices in my example above. In that case `\quad` would make nice spacing but it wouldn't fill the whole line.

Comment: You should not be using flexible space to do the spacing. It is more pleasing to the eye that these spacings comes in fixed amounts.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the solution that's best for you depends on whether you want *maximal* or simply *consistent* spacing between the items in the display equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can abuse the `flalign` environment; here are two realizations, in the first one I don't use the whole available space by adding two empty blocks at either end.

However, my advice is to use just `\quad` or `\qquad` between the items, so as to ensure uniform spacing across the document. So I provide also the version with `\qquad`. In my opinion there's no battle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flalign}
&&\tilde{B} = \begin{bmatrix} CB\\B \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{I} = \begin{bmatrix} I_p\\0 \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_e & 0\\0 & Q_x \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{I} & \tilde{F} \end{bmatrix}
&&\label{eq:helper_params}
\end{flalign}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{flalign}
\tilde{B} = \begin{bmatrix} CB\\B \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{I} = \begin{bmatrix} I_p\\0 \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_e & 0\\0 & Q_x \end{bmatrix},
&&\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{I} & \tilde{F} \end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:helper_params1}
\end{flalign}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{equation}
\tilde{B} = \begin{bmatrix} CB\\B \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\tilde{I} = \begin{bmatrix} I_p\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_e & 0\\0 & Q_x \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{I} & \tilde{F} \end{bmatrix}
\label{eq:helper_params3}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think about: `\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xxxalignat}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredfalse
}{%
  \endalign
}
\makeatother`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I wouldn't bother: as I said, the third way easily wins when compared to the "automatic expansion" ones.